# How to change the cache-control in swagger-ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

In swagger-ui the header parameter for cache-control is set to no-cache. Is there a way to change this to a different cache-control type? such as public or private.

```
{
  "correlationid": "b58df02a-6690-4f66-8335-73ad26f8cea3",
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "date": "Tue, 04 Jun 2019 02:47:48 GMT",
  "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
  "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-length": "536827",
  "expires": "-1"
}
```

I would like to be able to send different header parameters so i can model different outcomes.

Comment: `Cache-Control: public` and `private` are used in responses sent by the server, not in requests sent by the clients. Client-side `Cache-Control` directives used in requests can be `no-cache`, `max-age=<seconds>` and some others; [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Syntax). Could you clarify if you want to change `Cache-Control` in _requests_ or in _responses_?

Comment: in the request. in Swagger can I add the attribute "only-if-cached" to the header of a request?